# Looping through a range, setting values if condition is met

Tags: excel, loops, if-statement, for-loop

I searched through the stacks but wasn't able to find a question similar to mine. So here's my question:

I want to write a simple macro that evaluates cell B2.

- If B2 has a value, I want the macro to paste a value from another worksheet (let's say: worksheet2, cell A1, which says "Award4455") into cell C2;
- if B2 is blank, I want the macro to leave C2 blank.

Then I want to evaluate B3 using the same condition (filling or not filling C3, depending on whether B3 has a value or is blank). I want the formula to loop through 7 rows (B2:B8), filling (or not filling) the corresponding cells in column C.

Here's what I'm trying (unsuccessfully - I keep getting various error messages):

```
For i = 2 To 8

    Dim Award As String

    Award = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value

    If Len(Range(i, "B")) = 0 Then
        Range(i, "C") = Award

    End If

Next i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We:

1. pull the **Dim** and the **Award** outside the *Loop*
2. fix the syntax of the **Range** statements

```
Sub dural()
    Dim Award As String
    Award = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Text
    For i = 2 To 8
        If Len(Range("B" & i)) = 0 Then
            Range("C" & i) = Award
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```